# Extract Client_secret id from azure key vault URL and pass it as a variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

How to get or extract client secret  id from Azure key vault URL in JMeter . Suppose key vault url is
https://vcloud02vault.vault.azure.net/secrets/RootSecret

I tried to hit the URL through JMeter and extract the client_secret id value from the response but not able to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot suggest a comprehensive solution without seeing your response, if the endpoint returns the client secret id in any form you should be able to get it using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), the Post-Processor choice depends on the response data type:

- For HTML - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)
- For XHTML and XML - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
- For JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
- For anything else - [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) or [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

You may also find [Stub function for Azure Load Testing](https://github.com/pnopjp/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/docs/azure-load-testing-stub.md) plugin useful